# Specify another pod's address as environment var in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to send some metrics to a datadog agent in kube. I also need to have one agent per cluster. How would I specify the address of the DD agent for other pods? It seems like it should be doable using downward API, but it doesnt seem to work. I already have a DD agent defined

```
....
  containers:
  - image: datadog/agent:latest-jmx
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: datadog-agent
....
```

want to achieve something like

```
...
  container:
  ...
  env:
   - name: DD_AGENT_HOSTNAME
     valueFrom:
       fieldRef:
         containerName: datadog-agent # causes the failure, predictably enough
         fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

If I hardcode the DD agent's address in my ansible templates, everything works correctly.

Any ideas how I can get kube to resolve the agent pod IP address?

Comment: You’ve received an answer. If that doesn’t work for you, _do_ state the problem in a comment. If that works for you, consider accepting it. In any case, the least you can do to appreciate people’s time is not to walk away after posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’ve a service for datadog, just use its dns name to forward all requests to it. If you don’t already have a datadog service, you’ll need to create one with its backend selector equal to the datadog-agent.
The format of the dns name varies depending on whether the service you’re referring to is in the same namespace or not.
More about kube dns here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/